# Admin logout warning

Tags: magento-1.8, admin, session, logout

Is there a way that I can warn admin users that they will be logged out after a set period of time.

EG 60 seconds before the session is timed out and forcing the admin user to login it pops up a screen stating "click here to renew" or something.

The reason is because an admin user spent 1 hour building up a CMS page however lost all of their changes as their session timed out.

Comment: can't you just higher the time for which sessions are active server-side?

Comment: I could but its just moving the problem though for example if I set it to be 2 hours and they dont refresh the page for 2 hours then I still have the same problems.

Surely it makes good sense to let your users know that they are being logged out after than just doing it and annoying them.

Comment: What if they don't see they do something, go away, have the popup thown at them (while the session has already expired) and they click "renew"? Their work would still be lost

Comment: You could do this, but a better option is to add an autosave / draft functionality to the editor. CMS pages are the only workload in the backend I can think of where a substantial amount of work can get lost without manual saves. The easiest way to integrate this feature it's to trigger the "save and continue" action through Javascript.

Comment: Otherwise you could consider https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/session-keeper/ for Firefox or https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-manager/bbcnbpafconjjigibnhbfmmgdbbkcjfi?hl=en for Chrome, which basically pings your server constantly while logged in to prevent auto logout.

Comment: This question is not really about Magento. It's more something about javascript I would guess

Comment: I would just a snippet of JS which get the configuration value, how long the session is active minus a small amount. Then you can just make _ANY_ request to renew the cookie. What is your problem here?